# display a dialog with a list in which item selection is visually similar to rotating wheel

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to create a dialog which shows a `single choice list` in `dialog content` similar to this,

[image: needed dialog content]

i tried `AlertDialog` from [developer.android - dialogs guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) but it looks like this [image: AlertDialog with single choice list]

which is not similar to my needs, also if i make a custom view with a `ListView` in it, still it is the same as what i tried with `AlertDialog`. so is there any other view or widget which can be used for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can find all you need :

1. https://github.com/wangjiegulu/WheelView
2. https://github.com/brucetoo/PickView